# How do I change the color of the breakpoint marker?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, themes

I've found out how to change the color of many breakpoint items, including `Breakpoint (Enabled)` (the classical red line highlight) and the yellow `Current Statement` line highlight (occurs when your breakpoint hits and you can F10 from there). But I can't seem to find the string that changes the color of the red circle in the left vertical scrollbar.

Does anyone know a way?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change the color of the breakpoint circles. Which VS version are you using? Maybe the [Visual Studio 2013 Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe) could help you.

Comment: @diiN_ I'm using 2015. Okay, what option changes it in that extension?

Comment: I didn't try it by myself but I thought it *could* help you. However, if there is no option even with this extension I think it's just not possible.

Comment: @diiN_ What an unexpected limitation! I can change almost any color in the interface, but not those markers...